# Append to csv only if row doesn't exist

Tags: ruby, csv, duplicates, append, unique

My code looks like

```
CSV.open("test.csv", "a+") do |csv|
 (0..array.count).each do
  csv << [object1, object2, object3]
 end
end
```

Let's say at some point in the iteration, `object1` has value `1`, `object2` has value `2` and `object3` has value `3`.
Is it possible to check in my `test.csv` file if a row

```
1,2,3
```

already exists, and so don't append the same row again to my csv file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
csv_file = 'test.csv'
existing_lines = File.readlines(csv_file).map(&:strip) # remove line breaks

CSV.open(csv_file, 'a+') do |csv|
  (0..array.count).each do
    data = [object1, object2, object3]
    str = data.join(',')
    unless existing_lines.include?(str)
      csv << data
      existing_lines << str
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: undefined method `exclude?' for #<Array:...>

Comment: Sorry, the `exclude?` comes from ActiveSupport. You can use `unless include?` in pure Ruby. I edited the answer.

Comment: hi @jan.zikan . what if I want to also delete the already existing row with the same value for a column? for example, in a CSV like: headers:"name","age","city" 1st row:"john","30",ny" 2nd row:"michael","35","miami" I want to append a new row "john","31","ny" and delete the row with "name":"john"?

Comment: Do you want do delete just rows where the name is duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did mine

```
    existing_dates = Array.new
    file = File.open(@renko_csv_path, "r")
    file.each_line do |a|
      fields = a.split(',')
      date = fields[0].tr_s('"', '').strip
      existing_dates.push(date)
    end
    renko_points.each do |renko_hash|
      CSV.open(@renko_csv_path,  (File.file?(@renko_csv_path) ? "ab" : "wb")) do |csv|
        if !existing_dates.include?(renko_hash[:date])
          csv << renko_hash.map { |key, value| value }
        end
      end
    end
```